# Using sqlite3 in Tk8.6

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite

To use SQLite3 with Tk8.5 and python, users commonly call the sqlite3 and tkinter modules separately via

```
from sqlite3 import *
import tkinter as tk
```

Ever since Tk8.6 was launched with a built-in interface to the `SQLite3` database engine, is there a new way to activate SQLite3 directly from tkinter? Or should I continue to use the above import statement to import sqlite3?

Comment: Tk doesn't have a built-in interface to sqlite3. Tcl has an access library included as a package shipped with the core Tcl code. If that package is not built, Tcl and Tk continue to operate as before. For sqlite3 in python, use a python package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to activate sqlite3 from tkinter. You need to import tkinter and sqlite3 separately.